# Running total to find first date a sum is reached broken by group by

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, cumulative-sum

Hoping someone can help, I have a query that does a running sum of transactions and outputs a date a sum is reached:

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE t_status='paid' 
AND event_id=12345
ORDER BY date_paid) AS base,
         (SELECT @sum := 0) init
WHERE (@sum := @sum + amount - refund_amount - fee) >= 20
```

This works great! Only problem is it only works on a single event id, I want the date paid for each event id where the sum is greater than or equal to 20, I've attempted a few variations including subqueries or joins but no luck, for example:

```
SELECT min(a.date_paid),b.event_id FROM
(SELECT  date_paid,event_id
FROM     (SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE t_status='paid' 
ORDER BY date_paid) AS base,
         (SELECT @sum := 0) init
WHERE (@sum := @sum + amount - refund_amount - fee) >= 500) a JOIN events_history b ON a.event_id=b.event_id GROUP BY a.event_id
```

Comment: Since 8.0 MySql features window functions.

Comment: What `MySQL` version are you using ?